# Issue with Queueable that invokes a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, queueable

In an attempt to reduce the number of SOQL queries being used within a trigger, I'm looking at moving some logic that doesn't need to be done real-time into a Queueable.  In one instance, I have an invokable flow that creates an Invoice record.  It looks like the Queueable is able to call the flow, and the flow completes without throwing an error.  However, the flow doesn't appear to create the new Invoice record.  Following is the code within the Queueable:

```
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

    System.debug('Beginning execute()');

    Flow.Interview.Invoice_and_Invoice_Line_Create_AutoLaunch flow;

    try {
        System.debug('order: ' + order);
        Map< String, Order__c > parms = new Map< String, Order__c >{ 'Order_Source_For_Invoice' => order };
        flow = new Flow.Interview.Invoice_and_Invoice_Line_Create_AutoLaunch( parms );
        flow.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('Error "' + e.getMessage());
        System.debug(e.getStackTraceString());
    }
    finally {
        System.debug('Exit execute()');
    }

}
```

When the flow is called directly within the Trigger using the same code, it works fine.

Is calling a flow from within a Queueable not possible?

Comment: People who bother to downvote a question and spend no time explaining why are completely useless.

Comment: as long as Flow is auto-launched, activated and the parms map key matches (case sensitive) to the corresponding Flow variable marked `available for input`, it should work.  You can turn on debug log for your running user to trace the execution

Comment: @cropredy I modified the flow to write statements to the SF debug logs, and I see them.  Its as if the flow runs but the record it creates is never saved.

Comment: any chance the flow-created Invoice has an ownerId that makes the record not visible to the running user?

Comment: @cropredy the flow was last modified by me.  I'm currently testing things in a sandbox where I'm System Admin.

Comment: If you go to setup | apex jobs do you see any error for the queueable?